# Как удалить часть html строки (Как выглядит регулярка)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Ребята как написать регулярное выражение которое удалить все после faqs ?.

```
    $str1 = "/faqs/broker-type";
    $str2 = "aaa <a href='/faqs/broker-type'>text</a>";
    $str3 = 'aaa <a href="/faqs/broker-type">text</a>';

    $patterns = [
        '/faqs/'
    ];

    $replacements = array();


    echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str1);
```

Результат хочу получить следующий:
То Есть удалить все после /faqs до одинарной,двойной кавычек и пробелов.

```
    $str1 = "/faqs";
    $str2 = "aaa <a href='/faqs'>text</a>";
    $str3 = 'aaa <a href="/faqs">text</a>';
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А ссылки всегда `<a href='..` или могут быть варианты типа `<a target='_blank' href='...'>` ну и кавычки двойные вместо одинарных встречаются. это все сильно усложнаяет выражение. Если бы ссылки были одинаковыми можно было бы что то типа `/<a href='/faqs/\K.*?'/` менять на одну кавычку ...

Comment: @Mike Кавычки могут и двойные быть и одинарные. Я не думаю что кроме href могут еще быть. Но знаю точно что `/faqs/` это в тексте не встречается.Тоесть если есть `/faqs/` значит это та строка которая мне нужна

Comment: А, я сразу не заметил, без `<a` вы то же меняете. с одной стороны проще, с другой - надо понять где остановится. можно обрезать после например все непробельные символы до следующего пробела или кавычек `/\/faqs\/\K.*?([\s'"]+)/` менять на `$1` т.е. вот те самые кавычки или что там после ссылки

Comment: @Sergey, откуда у вас в результате после `/faqs/` в $str2 берется одинарная кавычка,а в $str3 - двойная?

Comment: @Mike Я понял . обрезать пока не закончился одинарной, двойной или пробелом

Comment: @Visman База старая там и так и так хранится

Comment: @Sergey, я не про это спрашиваю, а про то, что если это у вас ссылки и вы получили такие результаты, то это уже точно не ссылки, так как отсутствуют `>text</a>` в результате обработки.

Comment: @Visman Я просто поленился дописать,фсе вопрос отредактирован

Comment: @Sergey Тогда то что я привел вроде правильно работает, надо конечно на подводные камни посмотреть на реальном тексте. https://regex101.com/r/5R6gdc/1  Кстати, для быстрой замены в тексте я обычно прямо на этот сайт (regex101.com) копирую текст и из нижнего окна забираю преобразованный :)

Comment: @Mike Да спасибо ,проверил,не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 $text="xyz /faqs/broker-type/abc/a.html  not_replace
        aaa <a href='/faqs/broker-type/'>text</a>
        aaa <a href=\"/faqs/broker-type\">text</a> /faqs/abcdef/xyz.php";
 print preg_replace('#/faqs\K.*?([\s\'"]|$)#','$1',$text);

 Результат:

 xyz /faqs/  not_replace
 aaa <a href='/faqs/'>text</a>
 aaa <a href="/faqs/">text</a> /faqs/
?>
```

Меняет все похожие места, концом ссылки считает пробельный симовол или кавычки. В реальном тексте могут быть еще какие то особые случаи, не рассмотренные тут, проверяйте.

Comment: отлично работает ,но если можно последний слеш тоже убрать будет шикарно,если нет то сам просто топо удалю последний символ,Спасибо

Comment: @Sergey Ну тогда убрать проверку на него и все (поправил в ответе), правда тогда могут совпасть скажем `/faqsnew/abc` и то же обрежутся

Comment: Все спасибо дальше сам разберусь.Ты бомба :)

Comment: @Mike, https://regex101.com/r/5R6gdc/2

Comment: @Visman Да, я то же хотел сначала `\K` подвинуть, но потом решил сделать косую после faqs необязательной, вдруг ее изначально нет ... хотя если ее нет то и менять там наверно нечего ...

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$array = [
    '/faqs/broker-type',
    "aaa <a href='/faqs/broker-type'>text</a>",
    'aaa <a href="/faqs/broker-type">text</a>',
];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $res = null;
    preg_match("/(.*\/faqs\/).*\K([\'\"].*)|(.*\/faqs\/)/", $value, $res);
    var_dump($res);
}
```

Comment: Неа, не совсем то или совсем не то.

Comment: @Mike спасибо за Ваши старания обосрать меня. Код проверен и работает. Работает так как я понял из вопроса. Получаю первую часть и вторую, после их можно склеить. Если они пусты значит работает другое правило.

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V Прошу прощения, действительно работает как то, правда я не понял как этими переменными потом пользоваться. но `\K` то зачем в выражении, что она делает ?

Comment: Этот код не работает на строке `aaa /faqs/broker-type/ bbb`, например.

Comment: @Mike _Последовательность \K может быть использована для сброса начала совпадения начиная с версии PHP 5.2.4._ [Пруф](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php), Для того что бы в результатах небыло текста после '/faqs/' до '".

Comment: @Visman Не вижу вашего примера, в вопросе автора!

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V, так у вас и остальные результаты ни как не совпадают с результатами автора :)

Comment: @Makarenko_I_V Да, но зачем это у вас ? Если убрать первые круглые скобки что бы не захватывать ту часть подстроки, а она была только как общее совпадение и при этом убрать `\K` то эффект будет тот же. И кстати `.* ` захватит у вас все до последней кавычки в строке, а не до первой после ссылки